# How to open the default p2 install wizard from an e4 RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to open the default p2 install wizard if a button inside my e4 RCP application gets clicked.

I'm calling `ProvisioningUI.getDefaultUI().openInstallWizard` inside my click handler to open the wizard.

Clicking this button throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
  at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:93)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.ProvUI.getDefaultParentShell(ProvUI.java:155) 
  ...
```

The stacktrace shows, that p2 tries to call `PlatformUI.getWorkbench`, but as far as I know this is not supported in e4 applications, dependency injection has to be used.

How to open the default p2 install wizard from an e4 RCP application?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the p2 UI depends on Eclipse 3.x compatibility mode code such as `PlatformUI.getWorkbench` it can't be used in a pure e4 application.

You can use the non-UI p2 operations as they don't need the compatibility mode code.

Comment: Thank you, but how to use this compatibility mode in this case? I found at least four different tutorials on this topic, containing completely different approaches.

Comment: If you want to use compatibility mode code you write a traditional 3.x style RCP not an e4 RCP. There are some people who claim to have got a 'hybrid' app to work but it is tricky and I can't advise on that.

Comment: So it is not possible to write my e4 style application and include a 3.x plugin such as ....p2.ui in this plugin?

Comment: If the plugin depends on org.eclipse.ui.xxx plugins or org.eclipse.core.resources it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Help/Install new software... menu contribution, it seems to be provided by the command `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.install`. Could you simply add it to your user interface or [trigger it programmatically](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Executing_a_command_with_parameters) as described in the Eclipse wiki?

I am not sure whether this works or expects the compatibility layer, but it's worth a try.